# c++ - How to extract first element out of a vector<string> and reduce the vector size by 1 in a loop

Tags: c++, vector

```
string line= "";
vector<string> tokens;
//populate the vector 'tokens'

//loop through vector 'tokens' until it becomes empty
{
    //extract out 'line' containing the first element of the vector.
    //reduce the size of 'tokens' by one through deleting the first element 
}
//use 'line' string one by one in the subsequent code
```

Suppose 'tokens' is containing two elements, e.g.

> cat, dog, bull

On the first iteration, I want to extract 'cat' out from the vector and reduce its size by 1. 
It will contain now:

> dog, bull

Now, I want to use this extracted element 'cat' (stored in a string 'line') in my subsequent code out of the loop. 
Next time I want to pick 'dog' and make the vector contain only

> bull

. And so on.
Thanks in advance for your ideas!

Comment: Modifying the size of a container while looping is fraught with problems.  Do you really need to remove the elements?  If you do, can't you process them all and then clear the vector in one operation?

Comment: This is called "popping" btw. You want to "pop" the first element.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? How about acquainting yourself with the API of `std::vector`? Do you find any useful functions?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Shrinking the size of a vector in a loop has essentially zero downside.  Increasing the size of a vector in a loop is the problem.

Comment: @ChrisCM You still have to make sure you do it the right way.  Also if you start from the front then it kills the performance.  A simple process all data loop and then a call to clear/erase is my go to.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify for OP that it's the removal and shifting of elements that causes the performance, and not the resizing operation, in this instance.  Size increase has the additional downside of memory re-allocations, a different level of "evil".

Comment: FWIW, you're using a vector as a queue. `std::queue` is an option if you're set on the use-remove approach.

Answer (score 3):

When iterating over a container with the intention of emptying it, it's easier to simply iterate as long as the container is not empty.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> tokens = {"cat", "dog", "bull"};
    while(tokens.empty() == false)
    {
        // Extract the data from first element in the list
        auto line = std::move(tokens.front());

        // Pop the moved element from the vector
        tokens.erase(tokens.begin());

        // Do work with 'line'
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That said, it's very inefficient to remove elements from the front of a vector, as all following elements have to be moved up. Consider removing elements from the back instead.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea. Actually, we want to use 'line' string out of the loop. There is a series of manipulations over 'line' in the following code snippet. So, we need to pop out 'line' string each time and after finishing the subsequent manipulations we need to pick the second element of 'tokens' and continue the same until it becomes empty.

Comment: @ShadowPhoenix Can't you simply put the processing in the loop? Try replacing `std::cout << line << '\n';` in my answer with whatever code block preforms the desired processing.

Answer (score 0):

```
tokens.erase(tokens.begin());
```

That's how.

Comment: Won't that invalidate the loop iterator?

Comment: [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) says that it gets the *next* element after the last-removed element, not the removed element.

Answer (score 0):

The std::vector provides the operation you seem to desire at the other end ...

```
std::vector<std::string>  tokens;

// the last token can be accessed: 
std::string tok = tokens.back();

// removing the last tok
assert(tokens.size());  // pop_back on an empty vector is UB
tokens.pop_back();      // removes element from vector - constant time!

// and if you get confused on how to load tokens in reverse order
// you can load as planned, then reverse the elements to do your work
std::reverse(std::begin(tokens), std::end(tokens))
```

Give it a try. I found working at the back of the vector easy to adapt to.

Comment: Removing elements from any where other than at the vector-end can generate a lot of behind-the-scenes shuffling.  pop_back() is constant time!

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way would be:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
// populate the vector 'tokens'
// ...

for (const auto& token : tokens) {
    // use 'token' string one by one in the subsequent code, as:
    std::cout << token << std::endl;
}
tokens.clear(); // If needed.
```